# Powershell list all members of local machine groups

Tags: powershell

Current script below works but it displays members in one line delimited by |. I would like to have one row per member table format.

```
$script = {
    $groups = Get-CimInstance win32_group -filter "domain='$($env:computername)'"
    foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Get-CimInstance win32_groupuser -filter "GroupComponent=""Win32_Group.Domain='$($env:computername)',Name='$($group.Name)'""" 
    } 
}
$output = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers.Name -ScriptBlock $script -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$output | Group PSComputerName,GroupComponent | Foreach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
    Server = $_.Group[0].PSComputerName
    Group = $_.Group[0].GroupComponent.Name
    Members = $_.Group.PartComponent.Name -join '|'
    }
} | Export-Csv "C:\Users\someuser\Documents\PowerShell\AccessOutput5.csv" -NoType
```

Results look like this

```
"DummyServer","Administrators","Wintel4OPS|LocalIs|Domain Admins|Win_EP_Accounts|Win_EP_Admin_USA|Win_EP_Eng|Win_EP_Delivery_Svc"
"DummyServer","Backup Operators","MSSQLSERVER"
"DummyServer","Event Log Readers","NETWORK SERVICE"
"DummyServer","Guests","UHT-Guest"
"DummyServer","IIS_IUSRS","IUSR"
"DummyServer","Performance Log Users","jdoe"
"DummyServer","Performance Monitor Users","MSSQLSERVER|SQLSERVERAGENT"
"DummyServer","Users","INTERACTIVE|Authenticated Users|Domain Users|CLIUSR"
"DummyServer","Guardium Services","LOCAL SERVICE"
"DummyServer","SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$DummyServer","SQLBrowser"
"DummyServer","SQLServerHADRUser$MSSQLSERVER","MSSQLSERVER"
```

This is hard to read when you have 200+ servers. How can I change the current script so there is one line per member server name and group would be duplicated and that is fine

Desired output

```
"DummyServer","Administrators","Wintel4OPS" 
"DummyServer","Administrators","LocalIs"
"DummyServer","Administrators","Domain"
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: I thought I was clear about output. I guess not so I added a small sample layout desired. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining each `member` with the `|` character, you can run a `foreach` loop for each of the objects in `$_.Group.PartComponent.Name`

```
$output | Group PSComputerName,GroupComponent | Foreach-Object {
    foreach ($member in $_.Group.PartComponent.Name)
    {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Server = $_.Group[0].PSComputerName
            Group = $_.Group[0].GroupComponent.Name
            Members = $member
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv "C:\Users\someuser\Documents\PowerShell\AccessOutput5.csv" -NoType
```